# make element go to the right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I can't make the icons stay on the right aligned with the text and with some margin between the icons. I'm also trying to put a numeric value (1,2...n) on the left of the li, but bootstrap documentation doesn't seem to have that.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">

<li class="list-group-item justify-content-between">test1<div class="text-right"><a class="action-icon" id="delete-test1" name="test1"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></a><a class="action-icon" id="edit-test1" name="test1"><span class="fa fa-edit"></span></a></div></li>
<li class="list-group-item justify-content-between">test2<div class="text-right"><a class="action-icon" id="delete-test2" name="test2"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></a><a class="action-icon" id="edit-test2" name="test1"><span class="fa fa-edit"></span></a></div></li>
<li class="list-group-item justify-content-between">test3<div class="text-right"><a class="action-icon" id="delete-test3" name="test1"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></a><a class="action-icon" id="edit-test3" name="test1"><span class="fa fa-edit"></span></a></div></li>
```

Comment: test1 is on the left and icons are on the right. What are you looking for exactly?

Comment: And for margin use `class="m[side]=[amount]"`. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: They are on the right but they are under the text ( not vertically alligned ) and there's no gap between the icons

Comment: You need them to be vertically aligned? Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: yes. basically it's that

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `float:right` to your icons div

```css
.text-right{
  float: right;
  clear: both;
}

.text-right a{
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">

<li class="list-group-item justify-content-between">test1<div class="text-right"><a class="action-icon" id="delete-test1" name="test1"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></a><a class="action-icon" id="edit-test1" name="test1"><span class="fa fa-edit"></span></a></div></li>
<li class="list-group-item justify-content-between">test2<div class="text-right"><a class="action-icon" id="delete-test2" name="test2"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></a><a class="action-icon" id="edit-test2" name="test1"><span class="fa fa-edit"></span></a></div></li>
<li class="list-group-item justify-content-between">test3<div class="text-right"><a class="action-icon" id="delete-test3" name="test1"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></a><a class="action-icon" id="edit-test3" name="test1"><span class="fa fa-edit"></span></a></div></li>
```

Comment: It is supposed to do it but doesnt.

Comment: Ok do you know how to put a margin between the icons?

Comment: `text-right` is supposed to set the `text-align: right;`. Not the `float`. You will need other stuff for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pull-right instead of text-right

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">

<li class="list-group-item justify-content-between">test1<div class="pull-right"><a class="action-icon" id="delete-test1" name="test1"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></a><a class="action-icon" id="edit-test1" name="test1"><span class="fa fa-edit"></span></a></div></li>
<li class="list-group-item justify-content-between">test2<div class="pull-right"><a class="action-icon" id="delete-test2" name="test2"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></a><a class="action-icon" id="edit-test2" name="test1"><span class="fa fa-edit"></span></a></div></li>
<li class="list-group-item justify-content-between">test3<div class="pull-right"><a class="action-icon" id="delete-test3" name="test1"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></a><a class="action-icon" id="edit-test3" name="test1"><span class="fa fa-edit"></span></a></div></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to add `display: list-item;` to your `li` items for the numbers and you can use margins and floats on the icons to align them in right.

```css
.text-right{
  float: right;
  clear: both;
}
.text-right a{
  margin: 0 10px;
}
.list-item {
    display: list-item !important;
    list-style-type: decimal
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
<li class="list-group-item justify-content-between list-item">test1
  <div class="text-right">
    <a class="action-icon" id="delete-test1" name="test1">
      <span class="fa fa-trash"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="action-icon" id="edit-test1" name="test1">
      <span class="fa fa-edit"></span>
    </a>
  </div>
</li>
<li class="list-group-item justify-content-between list-item">test2
  <div class="text-right">
    <a class="action-icon" id="delete-test2" name="test2">
      <span class="fa fa-trash"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="action-icon" id="edit-test2" name="test1">
      <span class="fa fa-edit"></span>
    </a>
  </div>
</li>
<li class="list-group-item justify-content-between list-item">test3
  <div class="text-right">
    <a class="action-icon" id="delete-test3" name="test1">
      <span class="fa fa-trash"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="action-icon" id="edit-test3" name="test1">
      <span class="fa fa-edit"></span>
    </a>
  </div>
</li>
```